# asp.net dynamic data field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I need a little help, I want to use the dynamic data field without any database and databasecontext.I have classes which represent data objects in my database, every class has properties and methods that handle the changes in the database.I want to use the dynamic data fields to be able to separate the validation logic from the UI.Every tutorial I have read is about using dynamic data with dbcontext and that does not work for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you would use the [Model Binding](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data) to do this